# What is the magnetomotive force exactly?

Tags: electromagnetism, definition, electromagnetic-induction

What is [the magnetomotive force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetomotive_force) defined in terms of the variables of and derived from [the Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Macroscopic_formulation)? The emphasis is on the mathematical derivation.

---

[The answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/602034/17354) by @NicolasSchmid is wrong as explained by my comments below that answer.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetomotive force is the magnetic  analogous to the electromotive force. For electric current. You might know that the sum of all the electric currents through a surface is
$$\unicode{x222F}_A \vec{J} \cdot \vec{dA} = 0 $$
There is an equation that looks pretty similar to it in the Maxwell's equations $\unicode{x222F}_A \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dA} = 0$

So in this analogy, the current density $\vec{J}$ behaves the same as the magnetic field $\vec{B}$. So since the electric current is given by the equation $I = \iint_A \vec{J} \cdot \vec{dA}$ it seems natural to consider the magnetic flux $\phi_B = \iint_A \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dA}$ as the "magnetic current".

Yout can push the analogy further with the two formulas$$\vec{J} = \kappa \cdot \vec{E}, \qquad \vec{B} = \mu \cdot \vec{H}$$
So, the the permeability $\mu$ is analogous to the conductivity $\kappa$ for electric currents, and the electric field $E$ is analogous to the magnetic field strength $H$.

Since the the electrical voltage is defined as $U = \int_{\gamma} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dr}$ and $H$ is analogous to $E$ it seems natural tol define the magnetic voltage $V_m= \int_{\gamma} \vec{H} \cdot \vec{dr}$. Of course, once you have the magnetic current and the magnetic voltage, you can define the magnetic resistance $R_m = \frac{V_m}{\phi_B}$.

The magnetomotive force has the ability to induce a magnetic flux. That flux will be given by $\phi_B = \frac{magnetomotive force}{R_m}$  so you can think about it as a magnetic voltage source.

For example if you have a coil with $N$ windings and a current $I$ flowing through, you know from Ampere's law that the integral over a closed loop that goes through the coil $\oint_\gamma \vec{H} \cdot \vec{dr} = N \cdot I$.
If you have a resistor in serie to a voltage source and you evaluate the closed loop intergral $\oint_\gamma \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dr} - \epsilon_{mf} = 0 \Longrightarrow \oint_\gamma \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dr} = \epsilon_{mf}$ So you can see by comparing these two equations that in this case the magnetomotive would be $N \cdot I$.

Comment: This does not clarify the issue. You seem to define and equate the magnetomotive force with the magnetomotive potential which you denotes as $V_{1\to2}$. You define the potential to depend on an **open** path. How does that path relate to the closed loop through which the magnetic flux $\phi$ is computed? How can they be proportional to each other by a constant $R_m$? How does any of it derive from the Maxwell's equations? $\oint_\gamma \vec{H} \cdot \vec{dr} = N \cdot I$ does come from the Maxwell's equations. But does it relate to $V_m$ and $V_{1\to2}$?

Comment: Just want to make sure you understand my question, I am saying the closed contour integral does come from Maxwell's equations while it does not seem to have any relation to the magnetomotive force. I would like to see a direct mathematical derivation from the Maxwell's equations. The analogy with the electrical circuit is not adding to the clarity of the matter but confuses it.

Comment: Sorry for the notation with $V_{1->2}$ and $V_m$ and the weird boundaries I used for the integrals, I editted it, so you can see that the integral over a closed loop is just a special case of the integral over a path. I thought the hardest thing to understand about the magnetomotive force was why it is defined like this. That is why I presented the analogy with the electromotive force.

Comment: Sure let us use the closed loop. That does not make sense. Are you alleging that $\displaystyle\oint_{\partial A}\vec H\cdot d\vec r=c\iint_A \vec B\cdot d\vec A$ for surface $A$ and some constant $c$? If so, that is wrong. What is the relationship you are trying to convey?

Comment: Well, the above is true for arbitrary $A$ iff $\displaystyle\frac{\partial\vec E}{\partial t}=c_1\vec B$ for some constant $c_1$ and $\vec J=0$. One example is the circularly polarized electromagnetic field. The question is whether this is part of the assumption of the definition of magnetomotive force.

Comment: I don’t know if what you are looping for is called the magnetomotive force. I only used the magnetomotive force to compute more easely the flux in a transformator or an inductance. Even on Wikipedia ist seems to be defined as N*I or ϕB⋅Rm, nothing more profound. Maybe I am wrong but I don’t know much more about it. And I don't see why $\displaystyle\oint_{\partial A}\vec H\cdot d\vec r=c\iint_A \vec B\cdot d\vec A$ is wrong, since$ \displaystyle\oint_{\partial A}\vec H\cdot d\vec r = N \cdot I$ and $\iint_A \vec B\cdot d\vec A = I \cdot const$

Comment: Wikipedia is not always right. Let us do this all from the first principle. How do you derive $\oint_{\partial A}\vec H\cdot d\vec r=c\iint_A \vec B\cdot d\vec A$ from the Maxwell's equations? Where did you get $\iint_A \vec B\cdot d\vec A=I\,\text{const}$ where $I$ is the electric current flux through $A$?

Comment: I thought since the magnetic field around a wire with current I is proportional to the current inside that wire (you can see that directly from the Bio-Savart formula), that means that the magnetic flux should also be proportional to the current in the wire doesn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117575/discussion-between-hans-and-nicolas-schmid).

Comment: I tried but failed to invite you into the chat room. No, that is wrong. You are confused about the geometry. Take your example. By the Bio-Savart formula, the magnetic field is perpendicular to the wire. A disk centered arond the wire and perpendicular to it is our $A$ and $\partial A$ is the loop or peripheral circle. $\vec B$ therefore has no component in the wire or our flux direction. The $\vec B$ flux through $A$ is zero. So $\oint_{\partial A}\vec B\cdot d\vec r=\text{const }I\neq 0=\iint_A \vec B\cdot d\vec A=$ magnetic flux through $A$.

Comment: I see where we messed up. In my initial answer, I said that $\gamma$ was a "closed loop that goes through the coil ". I meant trough the middle of the loop. It is not a path inside the wire, it is perpendicular to the current. So  $\displaystyle\oint_{\partial A}\vec H\cdot d\vec r=c\iint_A \vec B\cdot d\vec A$ is indeed wrong, (or right if c = 0) and $\displaystyle\oint_{\gamma}\vec H\cdot d\vec r=c\iint_A \vec B\cdot d\vec A$ $ would be correct. ( with A the surface attached to the wire)

Comment: What is $\gamma$ exactly? What do you mean exactly by "through the middle of the loop"? What loop? $\gamma$ is supposed to be the closed loop! So long as it is perpendicular to the straight current, your last equation is the same as the penultimate equation and is wrong. $\vec B$ in the wire direction is $0$, so is the integral on the right hand side. $c\ne0$. That is just vector calculus.

Comment: -1 because this answer is wrong. Just think about the problem in your own simple example of a straight infinitely long wire with current $I$. It should be clear to you applying simple vector calculus.

Comment: In the following link you can see an image of a coil. In my example, when I talked about $\gamma$ beeing a path going through the coil, I meant for example a path along the field lines as shown in the picture (which are in direction of the field so the integral is not 0).  https://www.quora.com/If-a-solenoid-is-an-electromagnet-then-why-do-we-consider-the-magnetic%E2%80%8B-field%E2%80%8B-outside-it-to-be-0

Comment: There are two integrals. Which one are you talking about? In your now clearer example, the left integral is of course not zero, which I have said being proportional to the current flux, while the right integral which is the magnetic flux through the surface that $\gamma$ encloses close to zero especially when the solenoid is tightly wound and thin. You are wrong to claim the equality. Please review the definition of flux through a surface.